# Multiple SQL Select and Where on Same Table

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

I need to make a query on one table in a MYSQL database. In this query I need to make multiple selects with different where's.

My current query is:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        last_name, first_name, user_name,
        SUM(rthours) as rthours, SUM(othours) as others,
        SUM(trthours) as trthours, SUM(tothours) as tot hours
    FROM data
    WHERE labor_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'
    ORDER BY last_name ASC
");
```

I also need to select the following two:

```
SUM(rthours) as vhours FROM data WHERE decription = 'vacation' AND labor_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'
```

and

```
SUM(rthours) as shours FROM data WHERE decription = 'sick' AND labor_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'
```

How can I combine all three selects into one query so that I can then use them in a table that I am outputting afterwards.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` within `SUM()`

```
SELECT last_name, first_name, user_name,
SUM( CASE WHEN decription = 'vacation' AND labor_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' THEN rthours ELSE 0 END) as rthours,
SUM(CASE WHEN decription = 'sick' AND labor_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' THEN rthours  ELSE 0 END) as shours,    
SUM(othours) as othours, 
SUM(trthours) as trthours, 
SUM(tothours) as tothours 
FROM data 
WHERE labor_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' 
/*missing group by*/
Order by last_name ASC
```

For aggregate function you should use the group function

Comment: This returns no records when used. It should as there is data in the table that meets the requirements of the select statement.

Comment: After some research I edited the above code to this: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT last_name, first_name,
SUM(CASE WHEN decription = 'Vacation' THEN rthours ELSE 0 END) as vhours,
SUM(CASE WHEN decription = 'Sick' THEN rthours  ELSE 0 END) as shours,    
SUM(othours) as othours,
SUM(trthours) as trthours, 
SUM(tothours) as tothours 
FROM data 
WHERE labor_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' Order by last_name ASC");` but it still does not return any results.

Comment: @Lawrence can you add your tables with sample dataset on http://sqlfiddle.com/ then it will be easier to identify

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UNION ALL`. It combines the results of several queries into one result set.

Look it up: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 0):

It will be a mess but you can can run those as subqueries:

```
SELECT last_name, first_name, user_name, SUM(rthours) as rthours,
SUM(othours) as othours, SUM(trthours) as trthours, 
SUM(tothours) as tothours, 
(SUM(rthours) as vhours FROM data WHERE decription = 'vacation' AND labor_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end') AS vhours
(SUM(rthours) as shours FROM data WHERE decription = 'sick' AND labor_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end') AS shours
FROM data WHERE labor_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' Order by last_name ASC
```

I can't run these since I dont have a table or data but its the basic idea that matters

Comment: This returns no records when used. It should as there is data in the table that meets the requirements of the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

This works:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT last_name, first_name,
SUM(CASE WHEN description = 'Vacation' THEN rthours ELSE 0 END) as vhours,
SUM(CASE WHEN description = 'Sick' THEN rthours ELSE 0 END) as shours,   
SUM(rthours) as rthours,
SUM(othours) as othours,
SUM(trthours) as trthours, 
SUM(tothours) as tothours
FROM data 
WHERE labor_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' Group by last_name Order by last_name ASC");
```

Thanks for the help!!!!